# Error while Building Android Apps with Jenkins and Gradle on linux centos platform

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, jenkins, gradle

I have integrated my build process Android studio with Jenkins and Gradle.When I run the build on Jenkins and error is coming 
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
00:04:56.154 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 1.587 secs
00:04:56.164 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
00:04:56.373 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/tools
00:04:56.414 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
00:04:56.415 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
00:04:56.416 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
00:04:56.416 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19
00:04:56.438 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
00:04:56.440 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-22
00:04:56.461 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-22/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
00:04:56.463 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23
00:04:56.471 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
00:04:56.473 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing legacy package: /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21
00:04:56.487 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] File not found while marshalling /opt/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having same warning.

In Windows, to the folder "android-sdk" I have given write permissions for Users and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Probably the SDK is read-only.

Have you checked the permissions on the Android SDK directory to make sure that it's not read-only?

Comment: yes have used this command sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/android-sdk-linux

Comment: And do those `package.xml` files exist, and are readable by the user account that Jenkins uses?

Comment: 09:04:56.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
09:04:56.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2
09:04:56.792 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
Now this error is coming
09:04:56.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
09:04:56.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Comment: Was the issue resolved? I'm having the same issue, what was the resolution?

Comment: For me changing permissions did not work. I had to copy the entire tree from /opt to /var/lib/jenkins (the jenkis home directory) as user jenkins to work around the permisions issues. After that I had issues with "You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:". The fix was to copy my <sdk>/licenses folder tree from my dev machine to the <sdk> location on my target Ubuntu machine.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr For me, the `package.xml` files do not exist at all. Why would that be? What is their purpose? The build proceeds and works fine without them. I'd just like to get rid of this error message.